# Does Query Dsl support jpa projections?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, projection, querydsl

It would be good to be able to use projections with Querydsl and JPA

```
fun findAll(predicate: Predicate): Set<OrderView>
```

`OrderView` is a projection of my entity `Order`.

I can see from the interface this doesn't look possible but is there a future version that supports this or a workaround?

Comment: JPA doesnt have projections. Which kind of projections are you talking about?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016491/dynamic-projection-with-spring-jpa-repository-and-query-dsl/74025775#74025775