# Dynamic projection with Spring JPA repository and query DSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I currently have a Spring JPA Repository inheriting `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` and `JpaRepository`.

I'm using the `Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)` method from the `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`, but I would like to do a dynamic projection the same we can do it with `JpaRepository` (like `<T> List<T> findByName(String name, Class<T> type)` for example).

I tried to add a `<T> Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable, Class<T> type)`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Definitely , you can use Dynamic projections from spring JPA , check out this article , point 5, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: @Harsh the way described in the article can't be combined with querydsl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this?

Yes, there is.

Version 2.6 RC1 of Spring Data JPA introduced fluent APIs for Query By Example,  Specifications, and Querydsl.
This you can use among other things to configure projections. Note  that only interface projections are supported.

You can use projections like this:

```java
interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository, QuerydslPredicateExecutor {}
```

```java
MyService {

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository repository;

    void doSomething(){

        Page<ProjectionInterface> projections = 
            repository.findBy(
                querydslPredicate,
                q -> q.as(ProjectionInterface.class).page(pageRequest)
            );
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the Hibernate logs, it looks like it requests all the entity, even if my projection require only a subset of column. Did i miss something?

Comment: Looks like the limitation to the requested columns isn't implemented yet: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2600